# How do you hand over files to the user?

Tags: uno-platform, webassembly

in a #WASM / #UNO-platform project, how do you hand over files to the user?

In my case I’m generation locally a PDF and had to download it or display it in the browser.

Any clue?
Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no API to do that directly, yet. But you can create a `data:` url on an anchor (`a`) HTML element.

For this you'll need to create some JavaScript. Here's how you can do it:

> **IMPORTANT**: following code will only work with very recent version of Uno.UI. Version starting with v`3.0.0-dev.949`+

### Create a ContentControl for the `<a>` tag

```cs
[HtmlElement("a")]
public partial class WasmDownload : ContentControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MimeTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MimeType", typeof(string), typeof(WasmDownload), new PropertyMetadata("application/octet-stream", OnChanged));

    public string MimeType
    {
        get => (string) GetValue(MimeTypeProperty);
        set => SetValue(MimeTypeProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FileNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "FileName", typeof(string), typeof(WasmDownload), new PropertyMetadata("filename.bin", OnChanged));

    public string FileName
    {
        get => (string) GetValue(FileNameProperty);
        set => SetValue(FileNameProperty, value);
    }

    private Memory<byte> _content;

    public void SetContent(Memory<byte> content)
    {
        _content = content;
        Update();
    }

    private static void OnChanged(DependencyObject dependencyobject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (dependencyobject is WasmDownload wd)
        {
            wd.Update();
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (_content.Length == 0)
        {
            this.ClearHtmlAttribute("href");
        }
        else
        {
            var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(_content.ToArray());
            var dataUrl = $"data:{MimeType};base64,{base64}";
            this.SetHtmlAttribute("href", dataUrl);
            this.SetHtmlAttribute("download", FileName);
        }
    }
}
```

### Use it in Your XAML Page

```xml
<myControls:WasmDownload FileName="test.txt" x:Name="download">
    Click here to download
</myControls:WasmDownload>
```

Note you can put anything in the content of your control, as any other XAML ContentControl.

### Set the File Content in Code Behind

```cs
Loaded += (sender, e) =>
{
    download.MimeType = "text/plain";

    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is the content");
    download.SetContent(bytes);
};
```

### Result

[image: Download Link]

[image: Save Dialog]

[image: File Opened]

### Direct support by Uno

<del>There is a [PR #3380](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/pull/3380) to add this feature to Uno natively for all platforms. You can also wait for it instead of doing custom way.</del>

The PR for `FileSavePicker` has been merged and the feature is now available in package `Uno.UI` since version `3.0.0-dev.1353`.